# Location mocking - google map detects the movement but my own application not triggering location change

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mocking, location

I am facing a strange issue. I modified official mock provider source code provided by google to mock some route for my application.

Using this code.

```
mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(elapsedTimeNanos);
                        mockLocation.setTime(currentTime);

                        // Set the location accuracy, latitude, and longitude
                        mockLocation.setAccuracy(mLocationList.get(index).getAccuracy());
                        mockLocation.setLatitude(mLocationList.get(index).getLatitude());
                        mockLocation.setLongitude(mLocationList.get(index).getLongitude());
                        mockLocation.setSpeed(mLocationList.get(index).getGpsSpeed());
                        mockLocation.setBearing(80);
                        mockLocation.setAltitude(mLocationList.get(index).getAltitude());



                        // Inject the test location into Location Services
                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockLocation(mLocationClient,mockLocation);
```

Google map detects this movement but my application is not getting location updates

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Dont you looping this whole process, something like below ?

```
private void startSpoofing(){
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockMode(mGoogleApiClient, true);
    while (mRunning) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockLocation(mGoogleApiClient, l);
        l.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            l.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES_MS);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Whenever you loop this, onLocationChanged method will be triggered